# Bean must be of 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have been following an online training ( https://www.udemy.com/building-an-e-commerce-store-using-java-spring-framework ) and when i finish the `applicationContext.xml` i get the following errors.

`ref="sessionFactory"` indicates the following:

Bean must be of `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` type less... (Ctrl+F1) Checks value types for Spring injections (properties & constructor arguments)

And `ref="dataSource"` indicates `datasource unexpected`.

I do not understand what i am missing. How should i correct this?

I have uploaded my project to github: https://github.com/arendkolk/Wholesaleproducts

applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.wholesaleproducts</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>club.wholesaleproducts</groupId>
    <artifactId>wholesaleproducts</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.190</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Does your application context start up? Maybe the error is just a bug in the tooling that doesn't properly understand `FactoryBean`s

Comment: No, applicationContext does not start up org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Failed to introspect bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on;

Comment: What's your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` or w/e? Seems to me you're missing Hibernate on the classpath or something.

Comment: My library is much smaller then the sample library. See https://github.com/arendkolk/Wholesaleproducts/blob/master/libraries.png

Comment: Your POM is garbage, you need to put all `<dependency>` elements under `<dependency>`. I'm actually surprised anything ran, I'm guessing that's a discrepancy between the code in Git and the one you have locally.

Comment: Also it's 2017, I'd strongly recommend using Spring Boot and java-based Spring configuration instead of the awful mistake that is XML.

Comment: Hi Milimoose, did you mistake my applicationcontext.xml for my pom.xml; i just added my pom.xml as well

Comment: No, I didn't confuse them, and it's malformed according to Maven 3.whatever: `Unrecognised tag: 'dependency' (position: START_TAG seen ...</version>\n\n    <dependency>... @11:17)  @ D:\Repos\Wholesaleproducts-master\pom.xml, line 11, column 17`

Comment: See: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ef11b93de9d34857790b6a4d1d9387d2

Answer (score 0):

In the pom.xml file put all your **dependency** inside the **dependencies** tag.Then it will build perfectly.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.190</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```